# What is causing this Mocha test to timeout?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, sinon

I'm working on a full-stack web application using React, Redux, Express, MongoDB and Mocha, and am having trouble writing tests that deal with mocking/stubbing Mongoose models with Sinon. At the moment I'm trying to test this route handler for user account creation:

```js
import md5 from "md5";

import { User } from "../models";
import { UserCreationStatuses } from "../../app/store/action-types";

export async function postCreateUser(req, res) {
  let { username, password } = req.body;
  if (await User.exists({ name: username })) {
    return res.status(500).send({ reason: UserCreationStatuses.USERNAME_TAKEN });
  } else {
    let newUser = new User({
      name: username,
      passwordHash: md5(password),
    });
    newUser.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.info("Error in user creation route:\n", err);
        return res.status(500).send({ reason: UserCreationStatuses.SERVER_ERROR });
      }
      return res.status(200).send();
    });
  }
}
```

And here is the test for it that I'm currently getting stuck on (with some ellipses where I've omitted other tests). I'm assuming that I'm causing problems by stubbing the `exists` function for my Mongoose model "User":

```
import { assert, expect } from "chai";
let chai = require("chai");
let should = require("chai").should();
import httpMocks from "node-mocks-http";
import sinon from "sinon";

import { User } from "../models";
import { UserCreationStatuses } from "../../app/store/action-types";
import { postCreateUser } from "../route-handlers/user-creation";

describe("Route Handlers", function () {

    describe("User Creation", function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            sinon.stub(User, "exists");
        });

        afterEach(function () {
            User.exists.restore();
        });

        ...

        it("should respond with a code of 500 when provided with an existing username, and any password", async function (done) {
            this.timeout(10000);

            let req = httpMocks.createRequest({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/create-user",
                body: {
                    username: "ExistingUser",
                    password: "AnyPassword"
                }
            });
            let res = httpMocks.createResponse();

            User.exists.resolves(true);

            await postCreateUser(req, res);
            res.status.should.equal(500);
            done();
        });

    });

    ...

});
```

In my test output, the "should respond with a code of 500" test is giving this error:

```
Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (F:\Web\what-about-a-band-called\src\server\route-handlers\route-handlec.js)
```

I had tried to extend Mocha's timeout, as you can see in the test, but that hasn't changed anything. Any ideas as to what's going on? I'm very new to using Sinon to stub methods, and I'm assuming that I'm in a little over my head by jumping right into asynchronous methods and Mongoose. Also, [here is the full repo](https://github.com/gusbmurphy/what-about-a-band-called) in case there aren't enough clues right here.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some more troubleshooting, I've managed to make it work, but I'm confused as to why it does! For starters, I was wrong to use `res.status` in the assertion, I should've been using `.statusCode`. The part that I'm now confused about is that the way to solve the real problem is to neither call `done()` nor pass it as an argument to the callback for `it`. After introducing `.statusCode` instead of `.status`, I got the following error:

```
Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.
```

After removing the `done()` call but leaving `done` in the callback argument, I get the following:

```
Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

Removing `done` entirely solves the problem! So, am I correct (or approaching correct?) in thinking that the problem lies in `await postCreateUser(req, res);`? Is that call both returning and resolving a promise?